# Is my proof correct? linear transformation over $\Bbb R$ has invariant subspace $\dim(U)=1$ or $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$V$ is a  Vector space over $\Bbb R$, and $\dim(V)=n$. A  linear transformation $T$ from $V$ to $V$.  Then,  **T** has an invariant subspace $U$ such that $\dim(U)=1$ or $2$

I read in many books, which contain a proof,  there is a complex root $\lambda$, such that $p(\lambda)=0$, so there exist $X_1, X_2\in\Bbb R^n$ such that

$${\bf T}(X_1+iX_2)=\lambda(X_1+iX_2)$$

**I try to construct a proof by myself: But I'm not sure**

Consider   characteristic polynomia $p(x)$. If $p(x)$ has a real eigenvalue, then  $\bf T$ has an eigenvector.

In not, $p(x)$ has no real root. $\forall \alpha\in V, \alpha\ne0$,  then $\alpha, T(\alpha) $ are   linearly independent.

Let

$$p(x)=(x^2+a_kx+b_k).... (x^2+a_1x+b_1)$$

$x^2+a_ix+b_i(i=1,2,\dotsc,k)$ all has no real root.

According to Hamilton-Cayley theorem,

$$(T^2+a_1T+b_1E).... (T^2+a_kT+b_kE)=0$$

$\forall \alpha, \alpha\ne0 $, we have

$$(T^2+a_kT+b_kE).... (T^2+a_1T+b_1E)\alpha=0$$

there exists   $j(0\leq j\lt k)$ such that

$$(T^2+a_jT+b_jE)\dotsb(T^2+a_1T+b_1E)\alpha\ne0\quad (T^2+a_{j+1}T+b_{j+1}E)\dotsb(T^2+a_1T+b_1E)\alpha=0$$

Denote $\beta =(T^2+a_jT+b_jE)... (T^2+a_1T+b_1E)\alpha $,  then

$$ (T^2+a_{j+1}T+b_{j+1}E)\beta=0$$

or

$$ T^2\beta=-a_{j+1}T\beta-b_{j+1}\beta$$

As $\beta, T\beta$ are linearly independent, so $\beta,T\beta$ span a invariant subspace of dimension $2$

**Is the above proof  correct**? Thank you!

Comment: What is $\bf A$?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick should be $T$. Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean with "If not..."? Every polynomial has a real or complex root $λ$ and then the kernel of $T-λI$ is non-trivial (for real $λ$ resp. in the complexification of $V$), in the complex case the kernel of $(T-λI)(T-\bar λI)=T^2-2Re(λ)T+|λ|^2I$ is non-trivial.

Comment: @LutzL   oh, I mean $p(x)$ has no real roots, for complex root is not considered as  eigenvalue for Vector space over $\Bbb R$

Comment: The proof is correct.

Comment: Ok, then please correct your first sentence in the proof to include "real" and change "p(x)" to "T" in "has an eigenvector". For the rest I concur with Olivier Bégassat. See also the classical paper of Sheldon Axler: ["Down with Determinants"](http://www.axler.net/DwD.html) for more on this kind of reasoning.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you very much! I have just found http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2009/03/31/real-invariant-subspaces/

Comment: and Proposition 7.17, p140-141 http://www.ms.uky.edu/~leep/LinAlg_Notes_F12.pdf

Comment: @lutzl yeah I had been thinking of eigenspaces. Thanks. Now I see the actual task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long comment: For any polynomial $p$, the kernel $\ker p(T)$ is an invariant subspace. For most polynomials it will be trivial, i.e., zero-dimensional.

Let $p$ be a polynomial so that $\ker p(T)$ is non-trivial and there is a decomposition $p=q_1q_2$ in mutually prime factors. Then there are, by the Bezout identity, polynomials $u_1,u_2$ with
$$
1=u_1q_1+u_2q_2
$$
and $u_1(T)q_1(T)$ is a projector on the kernel of $q_2(T)$ and vice versa. And at least one of $\ker q_1(T)$ and $\ker q_2(T)$ is non-trivial.

---

This decomposition allows you to split the polynomial until there is only a power $q^m$ of an irreducible (over the given field) polynomial $q$ left. At this point you have to examine the chain of $\ker q(T)^m$, $\ker q(T)^{m-1}$, ... , $\ker q(T)$ and find the largest power such that there is a drop in the dimensions. From that you can then construct a minimal invariant subspace.

Comment: really grateful for your help.  with comments